# Flutter - How to center text and hintText in TextField vertically

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

How to make the elements of textField all centered vertically, the text and hintText both are slightly below the level of the suffix and prefix icons.

here's the code for the widget

```
return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 20, 0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
    BoxShadow(
      color: const Color(0xff1D1617).withOpacity(0.11),
      blurRadius: 40,
      spreadRadius: 0,
    )
  ]),
  child: TextField(
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      hintText: 'Search Pancake',
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xffDDDADA),
        fontSize: 14,
      ),
      prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/Search.svg'),
      ),
      suffix: Container(
        width: 100,
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              const VerticalDivider(
                color: Colors.black,
                thickness: 0.1,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/Filter.svg'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
    ),
  ),
);
```

and here's what it looks like on the phone

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center`, change `suffix` to `suffixIcon` and add its padding with the same value as the icon's padding.

```dart
TextField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center, // (1) bottom -> center
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    // ...
    suffixIcon: Container( // (2) suffix -> suffixIcon
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0), // (3) add this padding
      // ...
    ),
  ),
)
)
```

Result (I use replacement icons):

[image: TextField]